# Jackson objectmapper ignore nested json

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert json to a map, but I want the `objectmapper` to ignore nested json, so if I have json like:

```
{
   "field1": "field1",
   "fields": [{ "field2": "field2" }]
}
```

I want the output like:

```
{field1=field1, fields=[{ "field2": "field2" }]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you can configure `ObjectMapper` to work as you wanted.

You possibly could consider making a two step conversion from the map of JsonNodes generated by the object mapper to the map which meets your requirements. Here is example:

```
public class JacksonIgnoreNestedMap {

    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "   \"field1\": \"field1\",\n" +
            "   \"fields\": [{ \"field2\": \"field2\" }],\n" +
            "   \"fieldX\": 10.2\n" +
            "}";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, JsonNode> map = mapper.readValue(JSON, new TypeReference<Map<String, JsonNode>>() {});
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue().isContainerNode()) {
                result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString());
            } else {
                result.put(e.getKey(), mapper.convertValue(e.getValue(), Object.class));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{fieldX=10.2, field1=field1, fields=[{"field2":"field2"}]}
```